# Student Attendance Record II

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, dynamic-programming

I'm currently working on the [Student Attendance Record II](https://leetcode.com/contest/leetcode-weekly-contest-28/problems/student-attendance-record-ii/) problem:

> Given a positive integer \$n\$, return the number of all possible
>   attendance records with length \$n\$, which will be regarded as
>   rewardable. The answer may be very large, return it after `mod 109 + 7`.
>
> A student attendance record is a string that only contains the
>   following three characters:
>
> ```
> 'A' : Absent.
> 'L' : Late.
> 'P' : Present.
> ```
>
> *A record is regarded as rewardable if it doesn't contain more than one 'A' (absent) or more than two continuous 'L' (late).*

The idea is to use Dynamic Programming to use the results for smaller `n` to calculate the results of bigger `n`. I'm currently keeping two lists - one to track `L` and `P` and the other - to track `A`:

```
MODULO = 10 ** 9 + 7

class Solution(object):
    def checkRecord(self, n):
        lates = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]] + [[0, 0, 0] for _ in xrange(2, n + 1)]
        absences = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]] + [[0, 0, 0] for _ in xrange(2, n + 1)]

        for i in xrange(2, n + 1):
            last_late_row = lates[i - 1]
            last_late_row_sum = last_late_row[0] + last_late_row[1] + last_late_row[2]

            last_absence_row = absences[i - 1]
            last_absence_row_sum = last_absence_row[0] + last_absence_row[1] + last_absence_row[2]

            lates[i] = last_late_row_sum % MODULO, last_late_row[0], last_late_row[1]
            absences[i] = ((last_late_row_sum + last_absence_row_sum) % MODULO, last_absence_row[0], last_absence_row[1])

        return (sum(lates[n]) + sum(absences[n])) % MODULO
```

The code works, but it *does not pass the Time Limit requirements* for big `n`. Even though, for `n = 100000` LeetCode OJ runs it for only ~220ms.

How would you recommend to improve on running time?

Comment: Hey. Can you explain your algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's often helpful to explain the problem to someone else just to see things clearer and come up with a possible solution. Here is what I've just realized.

We *don't actually need to keep the complete list during our calculations and only need a single row at a time*. Let's reuse it and recalculate the cell values in the loop:

```
MODULO = 10 ** 9 + 7

class Solution(object):
    def checkRecord(self, n):
        lates = [1, 1, 0]
        absences = [1, 0, 0]

        for i in xrange(2, n + 1):
            sum_lates = sum(lates)
            lates = sum_lates % MODULO, lates[0], lates[1]
            absences = (sum_lates + sum(absences) % MODULO, absences[0], absences[1])

        return (sum(lates) + sum(absences)) % MODULO
```

I think I've seen this technique before and, if I remember correctly, it is called "Rolling Array".